# Thymleaf | parameterized segment in a th:each

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to use a parameterized segment in a th:each, but I am running into this exception:
*EL1007E: Property or field 'author' cannot be found on null*

If I got it correct, it means that the object whose variables I'm trying to access is null, though through breakpoint and debug in my Spring MVC app I know for sure there are two elements in the list.

---

Here is the Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String getHomePage(Model model) {
    log.info("Recupero la home-page");
    model.addAttribute("reviews", mainService.getAllReviews());
    return "home";
}
```

Here is the th:each:

```
<div
    th:each="review: ${reviews}"
    th:assert="({review} != null)"
    th:replace="fragments/utilities :: test(author=${review.author},message=${review.review})"
></div>
```

Here is the fragment:

```
<div th:fragment="test(author, message)">
    <p th:text="${message}" class="mt-2 text-dark"></p>
    <h6 th:text="${author}"></h6>
</div>
```

---

Here is a screenshot of the Model at runtime right before returning the webpage to the client:
[image]

What's going wrong? Why does it say ***review*** object is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with your main Thymeleaf template. You need to account on [Thymeleaf Attribute Precedence](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#attribute-precedence) which indicates that `th:replace`will be running first, before `th:each` and replace the entire `<div>` element. The working code may look similar to ...

```
<th:block th:each="review: ${reviews}">
    <div th:replace="fragments/utilities :: test(author=${review.author},message=${review.review})"></div>
</th:block>
```